# Несовершенный вид к "заблудиться"

Tags: грамматика

"Ты что, никогда не заблуждался?" Правильно ли сказано, ведь меняется смысл сказанного? Получается, будто он не потерял дорогу, а имеет ошибочное мнение.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, неправильно. Глагол "заблудиться" не имеет парной формы несовершенного вида. Вернее, она есть (заблуждаться), но используется, как Вы и пишете, только в другом значении: иметь ошибочное мнение, находиться в состоянии заблуждения.

Попробую ответить на подразумеваемый вопрос, чем заменить отсутствующую форму.

Для передачи требуемого несовершенного вида к "заблудиться" можно использовать глагол "блуждать" (*Ты что, никогда не блуждал?*), но он имеет более широкий смысл (в т. ч. "странствовать", "путешествовать без определенной цели"). Если такая двусмысленность представляется нежелательной по контексту, лучше использовать составной синоним типа "потерять дорогу", "сбиться с пути" — но тут уже надо выбирать наиболее точный, поскольку это синонимы частичные. Самый близкий, пожалуй, синоним — "плутать" (*Ты что, никогда не плутал?*). но он имеет несколько разговорный характер.

Вариантов много, выбор за автором.

Вот подбор пары совершенного вида к "заблуждаться" может быть более труден. Иногда предлагают "сбиться с мысли" и другие подобные, но это весьма слабые синонимы. На мой взгляд самое точное — "впасть в заблуждение", но его почему-то нет в словарях.

Answer (score 4):

В значении "заблудиться" так сказать нельзя ("заблуждаться" имеет только переносный смысл), но отсутствие парного глагола несовершенного вида с нужным значением легко восполнить добавлением вспомогательного глагола несовершенного вида:

> Тебе что, никогда не случалось заблудиться?

Можно и иначе обойти проблему, если стоит задача сохранить глагол в личной форме:

> Ты что, ни разу в жизни не заблудился?
>   С тобой что, никогда не было
>   такого, чтобы ты заблудился?

Answer (score 2):

Вольное дополнение к нескольким ответам.

Вообще-то историческая грамматика глаголов "заблуждаться" и "заблудиться" не дает полных оснований считать, что когда-то  это были парные видовые формы. Как помню, неполнота парадигмы обоих связана с парой "блудить" и "блуждать". В историческом плане их можно рассматривать как парные глаголы движения, наподобие идти-ходить, катить-катать, вертеть-вращать.  У таких глаголов очень часто видовая парадигма неполная или супплетивная. Так было и с глаголами всего ряда, порождаемого "блудить"-"блуждать". В дальнейшем из значения сильно разошлись (первое вообще развилось в ставший запретным морф), но неполнота парадигмы сохранилась.

Answer (score 1):

**ЗАБЛУДИТЬСЯ,**  св. Потерять дорогу, сбиться с пути. З. в лесу. ◊ Заблудиться в трёх соснах. Не суметь разобраться в чём-л. простом, несложном.

**ЗАБЛУЖДАТЬСЯ**,  нсв. Неправильно думать, судить о чём-л.; ошибаться в своих представлениях, суждениях.

**БЛУЖДАТЬ**, нсв. 1. Ходить без определённой цели и направления; бродить. Рассеянно б. по дому. Бесцельно б. в парке. Б. по свету (скитаться, странствовать). // Бродить в поисках чего-л.; плутать. Б. в лесу. Б. в потёмках (также: действовать наугад, вслепую).

Итак, видовая пара заблудиться/заблуждаться **разделилась по своему значению** (физический и ментальный план обозначается разными формами).

**Вариант 1.** Он **заблудился** (сбился с пути, потерял дорогу), а ты никогда на сбивался с пути, не терял дорогу, не плутал по лесу?

В этом случае нам **приходится использовать синонимы** для обозначения незавершенного действия.

**Вариант 2.** Ты **заблуждаешься**.  А ты никогда **не заблуждался**? Тогда объясни мне, чтобы я **не заблуждался**. Последние 40 лет он **заблуждался** практически по всем крупным вопросам внешней политики и национальной безопасности».

Как видно, во втором варианте **две формы  настоящего и прошедшего времени успешно справляются с ситуацией,** так как действие рассматривается как незаконченный процесс в прошлом или настоящем.